# problme with changing control values from a diffrent page

Tags: asp.net

i am using c# aspx , what i'm trying to do is to change a button.visible value from another page.

my page is build from 1 main page and 2 iframes ,the main page uses as a menu, iframe 1 is a login page and iframe 2 is the pages of my site.

on the menu page i have an admin control button which allows me to edit my database , this button visibility is false by default, then , if an administrator is logged in at the login iframe, the button should get visible.

i have tried in so many way to change that button but none worked ,

what i have tried so far:

1) send the button in a session ,recive on other page and change -not working

2) send the whole page and change - not working .

3) make the button public static and change -  not working .

i have noticed that even when i change the text on the button on the other page ,on the menu page (the page where the button lays) the button didn't changed it's text.

anothere thing i have noticed is when i press a button on a page , the page is sort of updating (like refreshing but keeps values) , is there a way to make this kind of update manualy?

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your description that you are trying to change the visibility of the button on the other frame from a post back within the log in frame.  The short answer is that this will not work because there is nothing being sent from the server to the client for the other frame.

Your would need to set the visibility of the button in a post back of the page containing the button (which is in the other frame).

It may be better to remove the use of frames and use a master page to provide the log in portion of your page/site as this would allow you to change the visibility of the button in a post back for any page on your site.

For the attempts that you have tried, all three of these should be avoided because the controls are recreated every post back when the page is recreated and will also be disposed every post back in the unload of the page.  Since the control and page would be disposed on the first request if you access it on a subsequent call to the server there is no guarantee that the state of the page or control is valid.

For more details on the life cycle of a page, look at the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx